# Is there a way to turn off loop optimisation on both C++ and Rust compilation?

Tags: c++, rust, compiler-optimization

I'm looking for a compiler flag that will allow me to prevent the compiler optimising away the loop in code like this:

```
void func() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> up1(new int(0)), up2;
    up2 = move(up1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        if(up2) {
            *up2 += 1;
        }
    }
    if(up2)
        printf("%d", *up2);
}
```

in both C++ and Rust code. I'm trying to compare similar sections of code in terms of speed and running this loop rather than just evaluating the overall result is important. Since Rust statically guarantees that the pointer ownership hasn't been moved, it doesn't need the null pointer checks on each iteration of the loop and I would imagine therefore it would produce faster code if the loop couldn't be optimised out for whatever reason.

Rust compiles using an LLVM backend, so I would preferably be using that for C++ as well.

Comment: Try `volatile int i`.

Comment: Another option would be to put it in a separate module and compile with `-O0`

Comment: And what is the intention? If compiler can optimize the theoretical result of such tests are absolute useless. So why spend time on this hypothetical issues?

Comment: This question cannot have one answer for both Rust and C++. Please pick one and adjust the question as appropriate.

Comment: This question is unfortunately quite incomplete. Measuring the performance of unoptimized code is pointless, so what do you want to measure here if not the loop? The cost of `*up2 += 1;`?

Comment: go watch this video on microbenchmarking.   It's long, but it's very informative and entertaining as well.  It has a lot of good info as well as a very specific, very good answer to your question involving inserting 0-instruction inline assembly.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk

Comment: Have you seen [Tuning C++: Benchmarks, and CPUs, and Compilers! Oh My!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk) by Chandler Carruth (CppCon 2015)? Highly informational.

Comment: @MatthieuM. beat you

Comment: @xaxxon: I see no link in your comment, but might you be talking about the video I linked? Okay I NOW see a link in your comment, cheater :P

Comment: @user1320881: `volatile` is likely to prevent vectorization, so unless we know what the OP wishes to measure, it may or may not be the right answer.

Comment: @Klaus I'm trying to measure the difference between Rust and C++ code when something that's statically checked at compile time in Rust has to be manually checked in C++. This has to be checked on each access of the pointer in C++ so I want multiple accesses of the pointer to happen, hence the loop that I don't want optimised out.

Comment: @HarveyAdcock: What's `up2`? Can we get a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Do you want to measure the performance of the `*up2 += 1;` statement?

Comment: @Shepmaster but if there's a solution for LLVM wouldn't that be applicable to both Rust and C++? The only reason I didn't phrase this as a solely LLVM question is in case there was a decent way without changing optimisation settings.

Comment: You'd have to be able to pass LLVM options to both compilers and doing that would require compiler-specific options, making the answer specific to one compiler or another. If someone provides a great answer for C++ and another person a great answer for Rust, which will you accept?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Have updated the question to show the relevant parts of the question to what I'm looking at in terms of performance improvement in Rust. So it's essentially what the overhead of checking for null-ness would be that I'm interested in.

Comment: @HarveyAdcock: Thanks for the update :) Are you trying to check the overhead of null checks specifically? And if so, are you interested in null checks in loops? Or null checks in "straight" code (no loop)? Because of branch prediction the "overhead" might vary between both cases.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ah, I hadn't thought about branch prediction, I was mainly thinking about in straight code, which is probably what's making any attempts I've made at forcing the loop end up similar times for both! Although the check would still need to be processed, so I would've imagined at least a small slowdown.

Answer (score 2):

In Rust you can use [`test::black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/benchmark-tests.html).

In C++ (using gcc) `asm volatile("" : "+r" (datum));`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287064/how-not-to-optimize-away-mechanics-of-a-folly-function).

Answer (score 1):

One typical way to avoid having the compiler optimize away loops is to make their bounds indeterminate at compile time.  In this example, rather than looping up to `10000000`, loop up to a count which is read from `stdin` or `argv`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Right, but the OP seems to be interested in "running this loop rather than just evaluating the overall result" which unrolling doesn't harm.

Comment: It's the "seems" that I'm trying to unravel. It's not clear to me what they are trying to measure here...